# Android studio IDE choose dependency dialog

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, settings

I am unable select any external library in my project other than com.google libs from the 'Choose Dependency libraries' dialog in the android studio 3.01.
I am not sure of any missing gradle settings and this issue exists even in any new Android studio project. Any help in resolving this is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your build.gradle file-:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below code in `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
}
```

And if you want add other third party library then visit it's doc section you find gradle dependecy for it.

[Read more about add third library in Android Studio projects.](https://www.androidauthority.com/add-a-github-library-to-android-studio-using-maven-jcenter-jitpack-777050/)

[How to use/import library in Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7sHAYYubJo)

Comment: I am aware of updating the dependencies in build.gradle. but i would like to add libraries through the UI dilaog. this gives a flexibility to look at all available libraries and select the right version. Previously i used to add through the UI, but now after updating to Android studio 3.01, it stopped working. I am not able figure out the fix for this issue.